# Separating function declarations in an LBNF grammar

Tags: bnfc

I have the following simple LBNF grammar (it's a fragment, don't try to compile):

```
ProgDef .  Program ::= [FunDec] ;

TypeBit    . Type  ::= "Bit" ;

position token Var ((lower | '_') (letter | digit | '_' | '\'')*) ;

FunArg . Arg ::= Var ;
separator Arg " " ;

FunDef . Function ::= Var [Arg] "=" Term ;

FunDecl . FunDec ::= Var "::" Type Function ;
separator FunDec "#" ;
```

When I parse the following source code:

```
main :: Bit   
main = fun1 fun2
#
main :: Bit
main = fun1 fun2
```

The syntax and parsing work fine. However, I want to get rid of the '#' character separating the function declarations and replace it with an empty line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
layout toplevel ;

ProgDef .  Program ::= [FunDec] ;

FunArg . Arg ::= Var ;
separator Arg " " ;

FunDef . Function ::= Var [Arg] "=" Term ;

FunDecl . FunDec ::= Var "::" Type ";" Function ";" ;
separator FunDec "" ;
```